# Symfony Constraint Collection - must have ONE of many fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following validation constraint.

Now, `search` is a must have field.
At least one of [`id`, `sku` or `name`] MUST be present as well, all can be present as well.

How can I specify that [`id`, `sku` or `name`] must be present and valid?

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


        $validator = new Assert\Collection([
            'allowExtraFields' => true,
            'fields' => [
                'search' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
                'id' => new Assert\Optional(new Assert\NotBlank()),
                'sku' => new Assert\Optional(new Assert\NotBlank()),
                'name' => new Assert\Optional(new Assert\NotBlank()),
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you [Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html)

```
class MyEntity
{
    private $fieldA;

    private $fieldB;

    /**
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     expression="this.fieldA != '' || this.fieldB != '' || value != ''",
     *     message="Either field A or field B or field C must be set"
     * )
     */
    private $fieldC;
}
```

Or [Callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback({"Acme\Validator", "validate"})
 */
class Author
{
}
```

I would give you examples to your piece of code, but I don't know the context of it. What your classes has. But I've tried to give the path. Happy hacking ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar albeit without needing a must have field. In my case I used a count as one of the constraints along side a collection so that at least 1 field had to be present out of 3, I defined it like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Count(min=1)
 * @Assert\Collection(
 *     fields = {
 *         "loginAt" = @Assert\Optional({
 *              @Assert\Type("DateTime"),
 *              @Assert\NotBlank()
 *          }),
 *         "firstSeenAt" = @Assert\Optional({
 *              @Assert\Type("DateTime"),
 *              @Assert\NotBlank()
 *         }),
 *         "lastSeenAt" = @Assert\Optional({
 *              @Assert\Type("DateTime"),
 *              @Assert\NotBlank()
 *         })
 *     }
 * )
 */
private $visit;
```

If possible to do a validation check on `search` separately then something like this should work.